# Composer auto scaling?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

Given that GCP Cloud Composer is running with GKE/GCE, is it auto scaling?

Now I have 3 nodes in the cluster to support say, 100 DAGs.

Later, if I have about 300 DAGs, will it scale up itself (w/ celery workers)?

Comment: Do you have any idea whether cloud composer supports auto scaling or not? I was creating infrastructure using Terraform but I don't see any such option of auto-scaling there. Is it still not there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No autoscaling at this point, but I expect it's in the roadmap.

Astronomer is working on an autoscaling Airflow service using Kubernetes, it'll probably launch around the time Google Composer launches autoscaling... so good times are coming :)

Comment: Hey @ryw, do you have any idea whether cloud composer supports auto scaling or not? I was creating infrastructure using Terraform but I don't see any such option of auto-scaling there. Is it still not there?

Comment: unfortunately i'm not sure how/when they will support autoscaling.

Answer (score 5):

We currently don't support auto-scaling but it's on our roadmap. You could however manually scale up/down the GKE cluster by updating the [nodeCount](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.environments#EnvironmentConfig) value.

Answer (score 5):

I just published an article showing how to enable autoscale in its underlying kubernetes https://link.medium.com/AMUlwUIkD0.

Basically:

1. Enable autoscale on the node level
2. Apply HorizontalPodAutoscaler to airflow-worker deployment
3. Increase some airflow config parameter to remove the bottleneck

This has been tested in composer-1.7.2 and composer-1.7.5 but might be applicable to other version as well

Do check it out

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Composer brings native support for [Environment Scaling](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/environment-scaling) since major version 2:

```shell
gcloud beta composer composer environments update <ENVIRONMENT_NAME> \
--location <LOCATION> \
--min-workers <WORKERS_MIN> \
--max-workers <WORKERS_MAX>
```

See [Scale Environments](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/scale-environments#gcloud)